# Inverse of matrix whose row sums is 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a $10 $x$ 10$ invertible matrix with real entries, the sum of whose rows is $1$, prove that for the inverse, the sum of the elements in each row is $1$ ?  {Question from TIFR GS-2015}

Comment: Can you get anywhere on this problem? Do you know what a "row stochastic matrix" is? Can you solve the problem for $2\times2$ matrices?

Comment: Unless you are defining "stochastic matrix" differently from usual, the statement is not true because the inverse of a stochastic matrix can contain negative entries in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Sum of all rows equals $1$" means precisely that the vector $(1, \dotsc, 1)^T$ is a fixed point. Of course this vector is then a fixed point of the inverse, too.

Answer (score 4):

We have $\sum_j A_{ij}B_{jk}=\delta_{ik}$ and $\sum_k B_{jk}=1$. So

$$\sum_j A_{ij}=\sum_j A_{ij}\left(\sum_k B_{jk}\right)=\sum_{jk} A_{ij}B_{jk}=\sum_k \delta_{ik}=1$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $\textbf{1}$ be $10\times1$ vector with each component $1$ . Then $A(\textbf{1})=1(\textbf{1})$. So, $1$ is an eigenvalue of A, thus of $A^{-1}$ also. Thus, $1(\textbf{1})=A^{-1}(\textbf{1})$ (left multiply by $A^{-1}$), which implies that the sum of each row of the inverse matrix is also $1$.