# Asking for further clarification on "matrix whose rowsums is one"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I've been required to answer a similar question to the one in the post "Inverse of matrix whose row sums is 1" and I didn't understand the answer given by Jack Cunningham
"We have $\sum_j A_{ij}B_{jk}=\delta_{ik}$ and $\sum_k B_{jk}=1$. So

$$\sum_j A_{ij}=\sum_j A_{ij}\left(\sum_k B_{jk}\right)=\sum_{jk} A_{ij}B_{jk}=\sum_k \delta_{ik}=1$$"
I do realise that B is A's inverse and understand the first two stages of the solution but I don't understand the third and fourth stages of his soultion or what the delta notation stands for.

link to the original question
[Inverse of matrix whose row sums is 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144675/inverse-of-matrix-whose-row-sums-is-1)

Comment: I am also not allowed to post a comment as of yet for a question. I would've done it on the original post if I could, sorry about the inconvinience

Comment: $\delta_{ik}=1$ if $i=k$ and is $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Randall why?  I don't think i understand its meaning - (it seems to me to be a sum of the products of Columns of the matrix and rows of its inverse but I'm not sure why there are two running indexes (or is their multiplication the running one?) and how to know its value

Comment: $\delta_{ik}$ is just the $ik$ entry of the identity matrix.  You've assumed that $\sum_k B_{jk}=1$ (that's a row sum), so multiplying by this doesn't change anything. Proceed.

Comment: $A$ is the assumed inverse to $B$.  The argument proves that $A$ also has row-sums of $1$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now !